# ¿Cómo guardar datos de referencia en una cookie?

Tags: php, cookies

Obtener el código o dato de referencia es simple: `site.com/register/?ref=1232`

```
$referred = $_GET['ref'];
echo $referred;
```

El dato que se obtiene, es el consiguiente: `1232` pero este dato solo se muestra si existe en la `URLs` lo siguiente `?ref=1232` si no existe ese dato `GET`, no imprimirá el dato de referencia.

Como se puedo guardar el dato de referencia en una cookies con validación de `30` días. Para así poder imprimir `echo $referred;` los datos de referencia, aún así no exista en la url los datos `GET` o que es lo mismo lo siguiente `?ref=1232`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Establecemos la duración de la `cookie` de 30 días.

```
$cookie_duration = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60;
```

Obtenemos el dato de referencia para guardarlo en una `cookie` con el tiempo de duración.

```
setcookie ("referred", $_GET['ref'], $cookie_duration);
```

Recuperamos la `cookie`

```
$referred = isset($_COOKIE["referred"]) ? $_COOKIE["referred"] : "";
```

Leemos la `cookie`

```
if($referred != ""){
  echo $referred;
}
```

Ahora debemos establecer los datos para deshacer/eliminar la `cookie`

```
setcookie("referred", "", time()-3600);
```

Answer (score 1):

Para guardar el dato de `$referred` en una cookie durante 30 días puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$referred = $_GET['ref'];
$cookie_value = "Referred";
setcookie($referred , $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 dia
```

Puedes mirar mas información en:

[SetCookie() - PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/es/function.setcookie.php)

[PHP SetCookie() - w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_setcookie.asp)

Saludos.

Comment: Creo que los 2 primeros parametros estan al reves. $referred es el value no el nombre.

Comment: @MarioGuiber Gracias por responder y para leerlo solo bastaría de esta forma `echo $referred;` o existe algún otro procedimiento?

Comment: @J.Mick Mira estas formas para imprimir variables en PHP: [Imprimir variables](https://cybmeta.com/php-diferencias-entre-echo-print-print_r-y-var_dump)

Comment: @J.Mick Si te sirvió mi respuesta no olvides votarla como positiva. :)

Comment: @MarioGuiber +1 por el tiempo dedicado, pero me falto información en su respuesta.